How to call app owned metafields in shopify extension function run graphql?
---- run.graphql ----
query RunInput {
  cart {
    lines {
      id
    }
  }

  appInstallation(id: "gid://shopify/AppInstallation/73424761***") {
    metafield(namespace: "attributes9", key: "attributes9") {
      value
    }
  }
}

I'm attempting to access app-owned metafields within a Shopify extension function, but I'm encountering the following error:
Error 0: 
Cannot query field "appInstallation" on type "Input".


The error occurs because appInstallation cannot be queried within RunInput or alongside cart.
To fix this, you should directly query appInstallation without nesting it under RunInput.
Here's the corrected query to retrieve your app-owned metafield:
query {  
  appInstallation(id: "gid://shopify/AppInstallation/73424761***") {
    metafield(namespace: "attributes9", key: "attributes9") {
      value
    }
  }
}

This query will correctly retrieve the attributes9 metafield from the specified namespace.
Additionally, if you want to retrieve all metafields owned by the app, you can use this query:
query {
  appInstallation(id: "gid://shopify/AppInstallation/73424761***") { 
    metafields(first: 50) {
      edges {
        node {
          namespace
          key
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I attempted to run a separate query, but it resulted in an error: "Cannot query field 'appInstallation' on type 'Input'." Is there another way to query the app metafield in the CartTransform app extension?

The CartTransform extension functions are limited to accessing cart-related data, so querying the appInstallation metafields directly within this function context is not supported. You'll need to either move the data into product or cart metafields, or handle it externally via your custom app's API.
